# Draw Chart while Exporting Pdf file - Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, jinja2, weasyprint

I am using Jinja Template and WeasyPrint for PDF generation.

While calling a API, I have prepared the data in the back-end and export that data into PDF file.

I want include chart(Column Chart/Bar Chart) in the pdf file. I don't know how to include chart while exporting PDF. Because the data preparation and export everything should be happened in Back-end with single API.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: try using highchart.js there is option for exporting chart in pdf, and exporting data as well.

Comment: No actually i need not want to load in client side and export, In the backend only I want to export